# Invalid class string when selecting PackagName in SSIS Execute Package Task

Tags: ssis, package

When attempting to create a task to call another package from a server I get up to the point of selecting the package name.  As soon as I click on that I get this error "Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING)) (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)".

I have tried changing it the TargetServerVersion, tried it in existing project, new project but so far nothing seems to work.  Have done a lot of searching but nothing has helped.

## Here are the underlying details of the error

Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING)) (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.GetPackageInfos(String strFolder, String serverName, String serverUserName, String serverPassword)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ExecutePackageTask.PackageBrowser.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(String path)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ExecutePackageTask.PackageBrowser.EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, Object value)

===================================

Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING)) (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.GetPackageInfos(String bstrPackageFolder, String bstrServerName, String bstrServerUserName, String bstrServerPassword)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.GetPackageInfos(String strFolder, String serverName, String serverUserName, String serverPassword)

I would expect clicking on the search box to the right would open a screen to select from the available packages on that server.